# Assigning values manually to Tensors during training

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a seq2seq model.

I want to set the hidden state of the decoder to the hidden state of the encoder in the `tf.Session()`.

Doing something like the following just makes `LSTM2`'s hidden state refer to `LSTM1`'s hidden state object:

```
LSTM2.hidden_state = LSTM1.hidden_state
```

How do I copy it? I have tried using `assign_op = LSTM2.hidden_state.assign(LSTM1.hidden_state)` but get the error `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'` when I call it in `sess.run()`

Using `tf.assign()` in a similar way inside of the graph gives me the error `Input 'ref' of 'Assign' Op requires l-value input`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "feed" the Tensor during `session.run` call, ie, suppose new set of values are in numpy array `vals`, then you can do `sess.run(..., feed_dict={tensor: vals})`